# Do the System.ServiceModel.Routing Interfaces even do anything ? !

Tags: c#, wcf, tcp, wcf-routing

Lets says a Windows Service initializes a wcf client class (contains Proxy to worker WCF Service) and supposedly this client works through the Routing Service to map to the actual service that does the work. ""BeastyWorkerService""

I mean face it your client is configured to spew from Endpoint "net.tcp://10.0.0.xx/sample/ep_poopie", or more correctly to talk to endpoint "net.tcp://10.0.0.xx/sample/ep_poopie"
and the actual worker on the other end of the "-"routingService"-"  our ""BeastyWorkerService""  is poised to accept on that endpoint "net.tcp://10.0.0.xx/sample/ep_poopie".

If you kill the Routing Service the worker still gets the message and the work gets done..  I understand the router may be handy for broadcast protocol bridging or other tasks but I'm thinking the emperor has no clothes on.. Am I wrong here ?? What am I missing ?  I Love WCF but it assuredly can be painful....

Answer (score 0):

OK More testing validates   Unique address in the client to match same address exposed in the router can be mapped to completely different address in the worker 
via the filters & filter table in the routing config ...sorry all that was fun